# Why can't I greet my friend?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

I recently started playing Fire Emblem Heroes and I have one friend registered. My friend has been able to Greet me a few times already and I'd like to repay the favor, but I cannot figure out how to greet him back, because the option to Greet is always greyed-out.

What are the rules for Greeting someone?

Comment: You can press the greet button once a day. This gives you a few feathers. Once you have greeted, you character can show up as a greet character (between all his friends) in your friend's castle for that day.

Comment: The problem is that I can't even use Greet once per day. It is always greyed-out; I have never been able to use it on any day that I've played.

Comment: That's weird. A friend of mine has the same problem. I'm guessing it might be slightly bugged, or we don't understand all the mechanics behind it yet.

Comment: I have the same problem!

Comment: I've been automatically getting feathers for greeting daily since I hit the button the first time. The button is grayed out as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [this thread](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/204447-fire-emblem-heroes/74946030), it looks like the reason your Greet option is grayed out is precisely *because* your friend sent you Greetings that you acknowledged.

> Yup! You auto-greet the first friend that greets you, or more specifically, the one whose character you first click on. That's why the Greet button is grayed out.
>
> You can greet once a day only.
> On a new day, you probably clicked on someone else's greet to you, which automatically makes you do your greet too. So the buttons is basically perma darkened unless you go out of your way to avoid other peoples greetings to you.

I have since been able to replicate this and it appears that you are informed that you are sending greetings when you accepted a friend's greeting:

[image: being greeted]

[image: sending greetings]

---

If you haven't done this yet on a day, then you should just be able to select Greet like this:

[image: friend list]

[image: selecting Greet]

[image: getting reward]

Comment: Better answer than your clone ;)

Answer (score -3):

I'm going to take a guess and say that greeting is when you tap on a character visiting your kingdom not sending someone to greet.

Comment: Guesses usually aren't good answers.  Once you have enough [reputation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can comment on any post.

Comment: I'm having an identity crisis over your profile picture...

Comment: @Vemonus I was really confused for a second because when you post answers, they're usually very well researched with links and everything... saw this answer and thought, "man, guess he's having an off day." xD

Comment: @Vemonus When I first saw this answer I thought "Huh.. I guess she changed her name _and_ got suspended? What's happened?" And then I clicked the profile and realized what was going on.

Comment: Seconded for seeing the avatar and having a little freak out thinking "Wha?! Vemonus in low quality posts?!"

Comment: @MageXy I felt obliged to post an answer to this to clear the confusion.